# Azure table storage with loopbackJS

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, azure-table-storage

I want to use Azure table storage with loopbackJS. Is there any library to use this or can any one please help me to how can i use this.

Comment: There is a Node.js library for Azure table storage at: https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node. The documentation is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-nodejs-how-to-use-table-storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loopback [doesn't have a commercial](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Database-connectors.html) Azure Table Storage connector available currently, and neither is there a [community connector](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Community-connectors.html) for it.

You can [write a new connector](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Building-a-connector.html) yourself, but that may be overkill/difficult for you.

If you're flexible about your [Azure NoSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28928016/microsoft-azure-documentdb-vs-azure-table-storage) technology you could look at using Azure DocumentDB which has [protocol support for MongoDB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-protocol-mongodb), so you could use the [Loopback MongoDB connector](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/MongoDB-connector.html).

Comment: Thanks for you information. Now i will tack a look at Azure NoSQL.